# How to filter, restrict and return posts based on custom user meta information

Tags: wp-query, functions, filters, hooks, child-theme

On this online platform project i have requested all users to add in their school title.

In the user dashboard there is a posts section which currently shows all posts. I want to only show posts that belong to users from the same school or institute.

I am working in the child theme and have possibly found out i would need:

```
add_filter( 'hook_into_theme', 'my_posts_filter');
```

I also understand, may be wrong, that i would need an array possibly. So the key is institute : value (whatever the users put it as)

```
$args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                 'key' => 'school',
                                 'value' => $??? what do i put here $current_user->ID,
                                 'compare' => '='
                                )
                            ) 
            );
```

How would i combine the function and the array to work to filter posts to only show those from the same school??

Here is my try:

```
    add_filter( 'theme_customisation_hook', 'my_posts_filter');
function my_posts_filter ($args) {
$args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                 'key' => 'school',
                                 'value' => $current_user->ID,
                                 'compare' => '='
                                )
                            ) 
            );
}
```

Does this make any sense?

Comment: This  is going to have to be a  2 step thing, you can't combine it into a single query

Comment: Would you say its a 2 step process because im trying to filter posts in the user dashboard specifically? I dont mind if this happens on a sitewide basis really, as im assuming when the users arent logged in the filter wont apply - or is it identifying the posts and then applying the query? Trying to see what im not thinking about or what im just messing up!

Comment: Because you have to figure out which users have that meta before you can then filter the posts, post queries and user queries don't mix, oil and water. There is no way to do it all in one go. Also, it's unclear how that hook works, you'll need to consult your themes support and docs for help with that

Comment: Thanks Tom from what youve said i think iv had to look beyond just a post to user match - that makes sense. One of the hooks i am thinking of using runs before every individual post is created and allows for the post to be filtered. What i am now thinking is that i am doing a user to user match e.g. does user a match user b i.e. they have the same meta query = then display post. So here id have to look beyond the post store the meta query info for the post author, match it with the current_user, if it matches display contents, if it doesnt, then exclude content = if else statement possibly?